# How to change date display

Tags: caml-query, spservices, date, date-formatting

[image][image]Currently the below code gives me a date display of:  2019-01-31 00:00:00.  I would like to see it displayed as:  31 January 2019 instead...

```
<table width="35%" align="left" id="myHTMLTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> 
<tbody>
  <tr align="Middle"> 
     <td>
        <b><span style="font-size: 18pt;">Due Date</span></b></td> 
  </tr>
  <tr align="middle">
     <td align="Middle">
        <span style="color: #548235; font-size: 25pt;">2019-01-31 00:00:00</span></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

```
getMyListData() ;
function getMyListData()
{                     
    var method = "GetListItems";                 
    var webURL =  $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentSite() ;                     
    var list = "Project Statement";                      

    var fieldsToRead = "<ViewFields>"+"<FieldRef Name='Name' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='FALSE' Type='DateTime'>2008-12-03T12:00:00Z</Value>" + "</ViewFields>";

    var query = "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Date_x0020_Due' /></OrderBy></Query>"; 

    $().SPServices
    ({
         operation: method,
         async: false, 
         webURL: webURL,
         listName: list,
         CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields Properties='True' />",
         CAMLQuery: query,                                                                                     
         completefunc: function (xData, Status)
         {
             $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() 
             {
                 var vDueDate = $(this).attr("ows_Date_x0020_Due");

                 $("#myHTMLTable").append("<tr align='middle'>" +
                    "<td align='Middle'>"+"<span style='font-size:25.0pt;color:#548235'>"+vDueDate+"</span>"+"</td>" + 
                 "</tr>");
             });
         }
    });
};
```

Could not get code in correctly, so hope you can understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are various ways to format the dates using plugins or custom functions. I will answer it using plain javascript. Use below code in your `completefunc`:

```
var monthsArray = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

$(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() 
{
    var owsDueDate = $(this).attr("ows_Date_x0020_Due").replace(' ' , 'T') + "Z";
    var date = new Date(owsDueDate);
    var dd = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();
    var vDueDate =  dd + " " + monthsArray[m] + " " + y;

    $("#myHTMLTable").append("<tr align='middle'><td align='middle'><span style='font-size:25pt;color:#548235'>"+vDueDate+"</span></td></tr>");
});
```

Comment: I replaced what I had with what you provided, but now it does not show a date at all.  Not sure how to add code to a comment.  I'm not a very good programmer.

Comment: On the line var vDueDate is there suppose to be two "=="?  When I remove one of them I get "NaN undefined NaN".  With the two equal signs I don't get anything.

Comment: "==" was by mistake. It should be single "=". try logging each variable in console and see the what is the value of variable. For example. `console.log(owsDueDate);`. It will give you an idea where the code is wrong.

Comment: I don't have full code right now. Will post it tomorrow.

Comment: Here is what I get with console.log for each variable:       console.log(owsDueDate);    2019-02-28 00:00:00
    console.log(date);             [date] Invalid Date   [date] Invalid Date   
    console.log(dd);                NaN
    console.log(m);                 NaN
    console.log(y);                  NaN
    console.log(vDueDate);    NaN undefined NaN

Comment: That means the error is at the line we are creating new Date variable. I tried this same code on my side and it is working correctly. One more question the value of owsDueDate is a string or a number? If it is number then convert it into string before passing to new Date() function. If possible attach screenshot of the code you are using and this console logs.

Comment: I tried converting the number to a string, but the error says its no longer a date.  Screen shots added to original post above.

Comment: This is strange. I am using the same code on my machine and it is working fine. I have updated the assignment of owsDueDate in exact date format. try latest code from answer.

Comment: That worked....

Comment: At last :P ... Enjoy sharepointing!